# How to switch between 2 TextViews places on the layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have an `OnClickListener` that listens to `Button A` clicks. I also have 2 `TextViews` below the `Button`.

I want that on every click on `Button A`, the 2 `TextViews` will switch their places between them, like this:

Before clicking:

```
TextView A
TextView B
```

After clicking:

```
TextView B
TextView A
```

How can I do it? Is there a special function that meant to do that? or some kind of a trick? Thanks!

actvity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="start"
    tools:context="com.intap.tof.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtA
        android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
txtA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtA);
txtB = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtB);

float mAX = txtA.getX();
float mAY = txtA.getY();
float mBX = txtB.getX();
float mBY= txtB.getY();

txtA.setX(mBX);
txtA.setY(mBY);

txtB.setX(mAX);
txtB.setY(mAY);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All previous answers do not work because you use a relative layout where a linear layout will suffice.
If you have to go **RelativeLayout**, do the following in your click listener

```
    TextView textA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtA);
    TextView textB = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtB);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textALayoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) textA.getLayoutParams();
    textALayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.txtB);
    textA.setLayoutParams(textALayoutParams);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textBLayoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) textB.getLayoutParams();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        textBLayoutParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW);
    } else {
        textBLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,0);
    }
    textB.setLayoutParams(textBLayoutParams);
```

This will place **A** under **B**. You can do the same for reversing.

Answer (score 3):

Trick is changing the x and y axis of both views : 
Your xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="start"
    tools:context="com.intap.tof.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="A"
        android:tag="A"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtA"
        android:text="B"
        android:tag="B"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="switch"
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:onClick="onClickButton"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java Code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView txtA,txtB;

    boolean _isOnTxtA;
    Button btn1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtA = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtA);
        txtB = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtB);

        btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);




    }
    public void onClickButton(View v)
    {

        float mPos1x,mPos1y,mPos2x,mPos2y;
        mPos1x =     txtB.getX();
        mPos1y =     txtB.getY();
        mPos2x =     txtA.getX();
        mPos2y=     txtA.getY();

        if(_isOnTxtA)
        {

            txtB.setX(mPos2x);
            txtB.setY(mPos2y);
            txtA.setX(mPos1x);
            txtA.setY(mPos1y);
            _isOnTxtA = false;
        }
        else
        {


            txtB.setX(mPos2x);
            txtB.setY(mPos2y);
            txtA.setX(mPos1x);
            txtA.setY(mPos1y);
            _isOnTxtA= true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: can i ask you what's  the problem you are facing ?

Comment: I've checked out now but it still don't switching between the TextViews.

Comment: i have run this code and it is switching the views , can you post your code here

Comment: where is your onClicklistener ? have you check defined conditions here ?

Comment: I've checked and the OnClickListener is OK

Answer (score 2):

[`View.bringToFront`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront()) method may be useful.

Where your layout is like:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView A>
    <TextView B>
</LinearLayout>
```

To call `bringToFront` on `TextView A` will bring it front (the last position in the parent `LinearLayout`).

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView B>
    <TextView A>
</LinearLayout>
```

For more detailed example, below is layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/text_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text_a" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_b"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text_b" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In your `OnClickListener` (in your `Activity`) call:

```
View textViewA = findViewById(R.id.text_a);
textViewA.bringToFront();
```

This should work.

Toggling behavior can be achieved by this application. For example:

```
ViewGroup textHolder = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.text_holder);
textHolder.getChildAt(0).bringToFront();
```

`ViewGroup.getChildAt(0)` always returns the first child of the `ViewGroup`. So everytime you call `bringToFront` on the first child will be bring to front.

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood your answer. Do you mean to create another layout?

Comment: No, you don't need. The latter layout is just an example and it is dynamic result.

Comment: Now I understand it, but this isn't answering to my question. The TextViews aren't one on each other, Textview a is above textview b and i want to switch them on button click. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @IdoNaveh I confirmed my sample works. There should be some problem in your code. If you don't post your related code and layout.xml, I can't have any idea...

Comment: I'm not on my computer right now do I'll post the code in about half an hour

Comment: I have added the answer review it

Comment: @IdoNaveh My solution is about using `LinearLayout` for parent `ViewGroup`. If you use `RelativeLayout`, other approach like Azfaar kabir Siddiqui's answer would be suitable.

Comment: @hata Now I've understand how to use your solution. I'll try and Let you know if it works